# Spring Boot client to connect to existing JBoss EAP7 ActiveMQ

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, activemq-classic

I've been searching the web but I cannot find an example on how to connect to ActiveMQ on JBoss (up and running) with a Spring-Boot client.

There'se a lot of tutorials from Spring but using an embedded Broker.

Any pointers would be great!

Thanks in advance,
ML

With the info provided, I've got this:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {

@Bean
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {

    final String host = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(host);
    factory.setUserName("user");
    factory.setPassword("pwd");
    factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);


    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the
    // message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}



@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Launch the application
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);

    // Send a message with a POJO - the template reuse the message converter
    System.out.println("Sending an email message.");
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("TestQ", new Email("info@example.com", "Hello"));
}
```

}

my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-optional</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But I've got this exception:

```
2017-06-01 17:55:54.176  INFO 2053 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 2.02 seconds (JVM running for 5.215)
Sending an email message.
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=127.0.0.1}
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:658)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:69)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=127.0.0.1}
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:333)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {wireFormat.host=127.0.0.1}
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:126)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331)
    ... 14 more
```

I don't know what is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect 
parameters: {wireFormat.host=127.0.0.1}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For configuration, **but change the broker url to your external ActiveMQ server**: see http://activemq.apache.org/uri-protocols.html for different protocols (e.g. tcp). You may also need to include a user and password.

I started with this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/ and made my own edits to get it to work the way I wanted with ActiveMQ, you can also look here for other options: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html. There are a few different ways to do this in Spring.

Also included the factory bean as well. From here, I use @JmsListener annotation to listen for messages and jmstemplate to post messages.

```
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;  



@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSConfiguration.class);

    @Bean ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://somehost:61616");

        factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the
        // message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Dependencies: spring-boot-starter-activemq

Spring version: 1.4.3.RELEASE